# Java - Ultra Light Client (ULC traffic inspection)

Tags: penetration-test, java

I'm working on security assessment of thick client application created using ULC. It is black box approach.
Based on wiki (wiki.c2.com): "Ultra Light Client (ULC) for Java is a widget set that enables a Swing Look and Feel for Servlets".

What I would like to do is to use SQLMap to test backend database. Intercepted traffic is classic HTTP GET/POST traffic with binary payload. So far I managed to setup Java to use proxy and I created a script to "decode" actuality to decompress traffic so what I have now looks like this (just a snippet):

```
Personal ID\00\0e\00\0bMaiden Name\00\0e\00\05Curr.\00\0c\00\10java.lang.Object\00\00\00\00\02\0e\00\10setColumnClasses\00\0c\00\10
```

Does anyone know how to de-serialize this payload? Is there any resource describing how ULC serializes data? What I would like to find out is how to alter POST request (is it just find/replace or do I need to update string length somewhere etc) and how to parse GET request (which hex character defined content length or anything else usefull) in order to forward some useful data to SQLMap and other tools.
It is not classical Java serialization which starts with hex: ac ed ... so any (de)serialization tool I tries is not working.

Thank you!